# How to generate unique links in Wicket application?

Tags: java, wicket

Our Wicket 1.5 application has lots of links for different tasks. We have a requirement that links our application generates have to be unique (and non-bookmarable).

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

By default every link is not bookmarkable as it contains the Page Version Id and is tied to a specific session.

Edit: Bookmarkable Links and Stateless Pages beeing the exceptions of this rule. Don't use them and you're safe.

2nd Edit: To make sure, there are no valid URLs from another session that work in a current session, you could add some unique value to your links by using or implementing a [MountMapper](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/request/mapper/mount/MountMapper.html) [as generally described here](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-pages/). This mapper could include a variable from the current websession as a parameter and check for that value when reading an URL...

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now. Currently first page load generates for a link an URL '/item_list?2-2.ILinkListener-currentPanel-...' and the second one '/item_list?2-3.ILinkListener-currentPanel-...' In the next session these links are still valid if same actions are taken. We should have URLs that are unique for a session.

Comment: @tputkonen See my 2nd edit... Just some idea, I didn't come across this usecase until now...